# Error in an attempt to simulate SDR frontend hardware in GRC

Tags: gnuradio

I was reading these lecture slides: https://web.mit.edu/6.02/www/f2006/handouts/Lec9.pdf
and I tried to implement some of the schematics shown there in GNU Radio.

On page 3 the author describes how using a single LO is suboptimal, because in the worst case, when the transmitter's and the receiver's LOs are orthogonal, the output will be zero. I implemented this in the following flowgraph: https://gist.github.com/ardavast/45b3fa0fb6e8ee9f3489a15a732549a9
[image: lo.grc]
It behaves as expected, if I move the sliders so that the phase difference is $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ the output is zero.

After that, on page 10, there is an explanation on how this can be prevented by using quadrature signals. I implemented this one too: https://gist.github.com/ardavast/f1c2f0296382bbc005e72ee034117e6a
[image: loiq.grc]
After I start it, I move the rx_phase slider to about 1.57 ($\approx \frac{\pi}{2}$) - this should make the rx_lo_i and rx_lo_q signals which are originally cos and sin, equal to, respectively, sin and -cos, exactly as shown in the diagram on page 10, the one on the right side. But contrary to what's written there, the signal vanishes completely, as in the single LO example. Where is the error in my flowgraph?

Comment: Um, there's a lot wrong in here – starting from the beginning: you should probably just be using a `float` signal source instead of a `complex` one and throwing away the imaginary or real part of that, just to latter piece them back together.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do this, because I want to be able to change the phase of a float signal arbitrarily - so I start from a complex signal which is then multiplied to get the needed phase (that's what the multiply const blocks, connected to the qt ranges are for), and finally converted to float. I don't know how to change the phase of a float signal directly.

Comment: but you're not using the signals as float signals at all. What you do is just complex multiplication with extra steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstood how complex signal source blocks work.  For example, I was expecting that a flowgraph like this one: [phase_diff.grc](https://gist.github.com/ardavast/2be4cc6db04622d65eca88531ca750ff)
[image: phase_diff.grc.png]
will produce two signals 90° out of phase with each other - but it produces two signals that are exactly the same.  If I multiply the lower signal source by 1j, however: [phase_diff2.grc](https://gist.github.com/ardavast/5e6d70e3eaacbb93f2b5d14e0a4128ee)
[image: phase_diff2.grc.png]
it works - and it doesn't matter if the lower signal source is set to sine or cosine.  Indeed, unexpectedly for me, a flowgraph like this one returns zero: [phase_diff3.grc](https://gist.github.com/ardavast/4b7b2d337505569d6730416dee691f19)
[image: phase_diff3.grc.png]

So if I change my original flowgraph to look like this - it works exactly as expected, and it produces the effect that was described in the lecture slides: [loiq2.grc](https://gist.github.com/ardavast/0fb52b541791829527d49e13a6116e32)
[image: loiq2.grc.png]